# How to show "the identifying key" when I cite it

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing

If you want to show an "identifying key" in your .bib file when you cite it, by using \usepackage{natbib}, you can add \defcitealias{the name of the identifying key}{the name of the identifying key}. And when you cite it, you \citealias{the name of identifying key}.
That is all.

Comment: This depends a lot on how you are creating your citations. Are you using `biblatex` or `natbib` or something else. This is probably easiest with `biblatex`.

Comment: For the part of bibliography, in preamble I wrote:
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

Comment: If you use `biblatex`, there is a `shorthand` field you can add to your `.bib` entries for these works which specifies how they are supposed to be cited.  See [How do I cite classical works with biblatex?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/31286).

Comment: Thank @AlanMunn. Since I am a very beginner of using Latex, I need some more instructions from you. Now, all book items are in a file named mylib.bib file. 
In the preamble, I wrote:
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
And in the paper of bibliography, I have only one sentence: \bibliography{/Users/prinelo/Dropbox/mybook/mylib.bib}
What should I do?